# Can hardcoding parallelism in Oracle hints lead to sub-optimal performance

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

We have a large Oracle 11.2.0.4 database (data warehouse). Our developers hard code parallelism into their queries e.g. (PARALLEL(16)). Multiple queries can be running at once, all with large hard coded PARALLEL hints. Is this limiting Oracle's ability to optimize degree of parallelism based on available resources?

(Trying to figure out if we should stop this practice and let Oracle optimize/maximize for us).

Comment: I think they should try out their queries without hinting and see what's the CBO deciding. Jonathan Lewis has some great articles on hinting and parallel execution: https://jonathanlewis.wordpress.com/2007/06/17/hints-again/

Comment: You can control resource allocation and availability for different users or user groups)  with resource manager (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/dbrm.htm#ADMIN027)  .

Answer (score 1):

Yes, yes it can. If the number of running parallel threads exceeds the number of CPU cores on the host machine, each of these threads will compete for CPU resources. This can be extremely inefficient and harm performance.

Answer (score 0):

Parallel is often seen as an easy performance boost.
The problem is that not every query can benefit from it and even if it can there is always a price. 
You can get a quicker answer but you use more of the systems's resources.
The Oracle DB will handle parallel queries by instantiating parallel query slave processes.
There is a limit to how many slaves Oracle will create and so you can very quickly use up all available slaves and then your query will simply be sitting waiting for a slave to become available.
The slaves have a certain amount of work to do and often one slave will be waiting on the output of another.

I have worked on a system where we tuned each process to get the maximum throughput and part of that was working out the maximum degree of parallelism each process could make use of.
Unfortunately we forgot to consider the points above so each process ran great on its own but we were getting very sporadic performance during integration testing.
As a first fix we lowered all of the parallel hints to half the degree they were previously which helped. However the most reliable solution was simply to remove any parallel hints  and let Oracle work it out.

This 2 part article is very detailed but covers a lot of the issues; http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/database-performance/geist-parallel-execution-1-1872400.html